# Land Ownership Data

Tags: land, data

I am conducting some research on land ownership within the Guadalupe-Nipomo Dunes complex located on the Central Coast of California. I need land ownership data but having trouble finding it. I was able to locate data for State and Federal Agencies, but some data is missing.

Does anyone have any good resources for finding and ownership data, especially private land?

I am using ArcGIS Pro.